# Aggregate function in mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new to mariadb, and I was using MySQL to develop something, after switching to mariadb it is not working, the error part I find is located at 'JSON_ARRAYAGG', in previously I was using JSON_ARRAYAGG to combine result as array by Group by as below

```
SELECT column1, JSON_ARRAYAGG(column2) AS column2 FROM table GROUP BY column1;
```

Transformation

```
column1    column2               column1    column2
1            a                      1       ['a','b']
1            b                      2       ['cc','dd']
2            cc          --->       3       ['e']
2            dd
3            e
```

Is there a way to do so in mariadb?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you could use MariaDB `JSON_ARRAY` function and write your own aggregate function which relies on that and then use it :-) https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/stored-aggregate-functions/

Comment: Caution - JSON was developed independently between MySQL and MariaDB; you will find lots of differences.

Comment: Info: Here you can find an overview of function differences between MySQL and MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/function-differences-between-mariadb-104-and-mysql-80/#present-in-mysql-only

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Creating an [aggregate function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/stored-aggregate-functions/) in MariaDB v10.3.3 :

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS JSON_ARRAYAGG//

CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS JSON_ARRAYAGG(next_value TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN  

 DECLARE json TEXT DEFAULT '[""]';
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN json_remove(json, '$[0]');
      LOOP  
          FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
          SET json = json_array_append(json, '$', next_value);
      END LOOP;  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it like this:

```
SELECT column1, JSON_ARRAYAGG(column2) AS column2 FROM table GROUP BY column1;
```

will work.

Comment: Worth notice that for me, this solution is stringifying each object if I do `SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT( ... ) ) FROM table` it returns something like `["{...}"]` MariaDB 10.3.28 giving an array of strings instead an array of objects, `GROUP_CONCAT` solutions works with `JSON_OBJECT`

Answer (score 9):

You can emulate it by wrapping the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group_concat/) with brackets using [`CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/concat/).

```
SELECT column1, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(column2), ']') AS column2 FROM table GROUP BY column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON_OBJECTAGG MariaDB starting with 10.5.0

JSON_OBJECTAGG was added in MariaDB 10.5.0.
and :
JSON_ARRAYAGG was introduced in MySQL 5.7.22.

If you have a space between a function name and the parentheses (JSON_OBJECTAGG ("item", item.item_id)). MySQL, by default, [does not handle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) the function name as a built-in function.

You can either remove the space between then function name and the parentheses or use sql_mode IGNORE_SPACE. Easier just not to use the space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP_CONCAT, I think that would get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2) AS column2 FROM table GROUP BY column1
```